# Gradle build error with explicitPluginVersion

Tags: android, gradle, build

I get this build error when building an android app

```
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Please set the 'explicitPluginVersion=X.Y.Z' in gradle.properties or run gradlew ... -PexplicitPluginVersion=X.Y.Z
```

what is this `explicitPluginVersion`

Comment: I guess somewhere in your dependencies you have a version with a + sign, e.g.  compile "this:that:1.2.3+". Can you show us your gradlle file?

Comment: Are you perhaps integrating a library that requires a specific version?